# How to display "This video is playing on ..." when Airplaying with AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, avplayer

Does anyone know how to display a "This video is playing on ..." screen when Airplaying with `AVPlayer`? Example from the VEVO iPhone app:

[image: VEVO app airplaying a video to Apple TV]

By default, `AVPlayer` just displays a black screen. Do I have to implement such a screen myself or is a default component available for this?

Comment: Nope, I never did. Still waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

May be this is a little late, but I figured out or at least a workaround for this. I added a UILabel, and to obtain the name of the selected device by using doing something like this:

```
CFDictionaryRef description;
UInt32 dataSize = sizeof(description);
if (AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteDescription, &dataSize, &description) == kAudioSessionNoError)  {
    CFArrayRef outputs = CFDictionaryGetValue(description, kAudioSession_AudioRouteKey_Outputs);
    if (outputs) {
        if(CFArrayGetCount(outputs) > 0) {
            CFDictionaryRef currentOutput = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(outputs, 0);
            NSLog(@"%@", currentOutput);
            CFStringRef outputType = CFDictionaryGetValue(currentOutput, kAudioSession_AudioRouteKey_Type);
            if (CFStringCompare(outputType, kAudioSessionOutputRoute_AirPlay, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
                NSDictionary *desc = (__bridge NSDictionary *)(currentOutput);
                NSLog(@"%@", [desc objectForKey:@"RouteDetailedDescription_Name"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There should be a better way, but this is a good approach. Also, AudioSessionGetProperty is deprecated, and this can be done using AVAudioSession.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

That image is displayed by default when using the MPMoviePlayerController. Since AVPlayer doesn't have an UI, that image is also not available if MPMoviePlayerController is not used.

Also, I don't think that the image is available as a component outside of the MPMoviePlayerController.